# Class is required but cannot be accessed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, require, nameerror

I have a very odd error I cannot wrap my head around.

Basically, I have this class in my `lib` folder:

```
# lib/api/amazon.rb
module API
  class Amazon
    ...
  end
end
```

When I want to use it somewhere, I `require` it:

```
require 'api/amazon'
API::Amazon.do_stuff
```

This works initially but after a while it breaks and raises `NameError: uninitialized constant API::Amazon`. When I debug this and try to `require` the file again when the error is raised, it returns `false`, indicating that the file was already loaded. I can also see it in `$"` (this list of loaded files). Why can I then not access `API::Amazon`?

Note: I added "API" as an acronym to `ActiveSupport::Inflector` which is why I don't have to use "Api":

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'API'
end
```

EDIT:

I tried `::API::Amazon.do_stuff` as well, same result.

Comment: It looks like `ActiveSupport` performs from time to time some cleanup on it’s nested classes, removing dinamically created. This might be needed if someone heavy uses dynamic class extension with `class_eval`-like methods.

Comment: Don't know exactly what you mean by that, @mudasobwa. I don't use any dynamic `class_eval` stuff, it's a regular class without any dynamic or metaprogramming magic.

Comment: You do define a class under already existing (and frozen, accorging to [their politics](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html)) module; say, you have monkeypatched `ActiveSupport::Inflector`. `ActiveSupport`, once loaded, may perform such a cleanup on **it’s** nested classes.

Comment: I added the acronym the recommended way in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`. I don't think this is the problem

Comment: I guess you mixed acronyms up: the recommended way is to add acronyms to teach `Inflector` on how to operate with. Refer to [this post](https://coderwall.com/p/vaw85a), for instance. You have added a class under _their module_.

Comment: @mudasobwa Check out the updated question. The Amazon API code I posted wasn't in the `Inflections` of course...

Comment: Ah. sorry, I misunderstood you; I thought you did alias for `Inflector` like: `API = ActiveSupport::Inflector`.

Answer (score 1):

I write some code aimed to get same result as yours, maybe it can give some clue.

trytemp.rb:

```
module API
  class Amazon
    def hello
      puts "API::Amazon initially works well"
      $stdout.flush
    end
  end
end

s = API::Amazon.new
s.hello

p API.constants
API = Module.new
p API.constants # Here you can see constant Amazon disappers from module API
s = API::Amazon.new
s.hello
```

It initially works well, then get same error,"uninitialized constant API::Amazon (NameError)":

```
$ ruby trytemp.rb
API::Amazon initially works well
[:Amazon]
trytemp.rb:15: warning: already initialized constant API
[]
trytemp.rb:19:in `<main>': uninitialized constant API::Amazon (NameError)
```

Comment: You have a mistake in your code ( correct me if I am wrong ). Only class can be initialized not module ( Module.new).

Comment: @maro30. You are really wrong. You are confused with Module and an instance of Module. For example, API is an instance of Module. In another word, Module is a class, and API is a module.

Comment: ok where does the `Module` with capital `M` come from? If `API` is an instance of it, then `Module` is supposed to be a class. Just trying to understand your code...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @uncutstone! It makes sense that you get the error with your code since you are redefining `API` (`API = Module.new`), so after that `API::Amazon` is no longer present. I had a look at my project and the only related thing I can see is that I have a `api` namespace for my controllers like this: `class API::V1::AccountsController < APIController`. I will try to change that to `module API; class V1::AccountsController < APIController;...` to see if that changes anything...

Comment: @Manuel Meurer. Have you fix the problem? Mabye you can add a debug sentence "p API.contants" in your code to see when constant Amazon disappears from module API. I add such debug sentence in my code above.

Comment: I did the change I mentioned in my previous comment and until now the error has not reoccurred. I will wait a couple of days and see if it comes back...

Comment: Seems like the fix worked... see my own answer. Thanks for your help, @uncutstone!

Comment: Nope, not fixed after all... :( Same error just occurred again. When I checked `API.constants`, it had only `[:V1]` in there, should have been `[:V1, :Amazon]`. So it seems like my controllers clear out the `API` module when reloaded... I guess the only fix is to use different namespaces for the controllers and lib files.

Comment: Can you make the error occur at any time? If you can, I think you can add `p API.constants` at some check points to find when and where constant Amazon disappears.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I though I had found the answer but the same error just occurred again... :(

END EDIT

It seems that I found the answer, with the help of @uncutstone.

Turns out I had not only used the `API` namespace for `API::Amazon` but also for some controllers, like so:

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/accounts_controller.rb
class API::V1::AccountsController < APIController
  ...
end
```

My theory is that one of these controllers was reloaded automatically at some point in time and re-initialized (and therefore cleared out) the `API` module/namespace.
Thus `API::Amazon` wasn't available after that, but re`require`ing `lib/api/amazon.rb` didn't help because it had already been required and therefore wasn't loaded again.
I changed the controllers to look like this:

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/accounts_controller.rb
module API
  class V1::AccountsController < APIController
    ...
  end
end
```

and now it seems to work fine.

Comment: It also seems like this is/was only a problem in development, in production the error never occurred.